# How does the "shrinking circle" quick time event work?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I just started playing the new Tomb Raider game and like a lot of modern games, it insists on those irritating press-the-right-button-at-the-right-moment minigames or quick time events to get your character through a sticky situation.

One of these is a shrinking circle where apparently you're supposed to press something at a specific moment, but no matter what you do it just doesn't want to work.

Does anyone know you're supposed to win this?

Comment: What platform are you playing on? [The PC Gaming Wiki explains that this QTE is bugged on the PC.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109327/4797)

Comment: @Fluttershy: That question is in need of a better title, but I can't just lift the one from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the PC Gaming Wiki's "[Tomb Raider (2013) - QTE (quick time event) Steamlining](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Tomb_Raider_%282013%29#QTE_streamlining)" guide:

> - **White circle getting smaller** — Tap repeatedly melee key (default <kbd>F</kbd>). This QTE is bugged - circle animation is out of sync
>     with trigger behind QTE and therefore it is difficult win this QTE
>     normally. Luckily there is no penalization for missing said trigger
>     with key press so pressing melee key for whole duration of QTE works
>     perfectly.

Comment: This worked fine... until I came up against the wolf. Now not even that works. Used to be a time they made games for the PC. Not we just get broken ports.

Comment: @Term See the [full QTE guide at the PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Tomb_Raider_(2013)#QTE_streamlining), it lists all types of QTEs and their solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a smaller circle with a fixed size, and a larger circle that shrinks. You are supposed to hit F between the moments when both circles have the same size and the larger circle disappearing.

Please see also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108299/how-to-make-fighting-easier-in-tomb-raider-2013) (and the answers) for more details on the minigames.