# Pressing 'e' does not work at the beginning of the game

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

When I press <kbd>e</kbd> in Tomb Raider: Survival Edition at the complete start it doesn't work when the metal spike is stuck in her.

What do I do?

Comment: Solution: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300488/80525

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the metal spike when she falls down, you have to mash "e" rather than press it once. You'll find out rather quickly there's a lot of Quick Time Events in Tomb Raider, from mashing left/right to scrabble up a slope to as well as opening chests.

Comment: IMO Quick time event in Tomb Raider is a little messed up. Dunno which one to press between E or F... why they didn't have put the letter in the circle ?

Comment: @Warface, I found the left/right scrabble worse, I didn't know wether to use the arrow keys or a and d.

Comment: at least both are working and imaged on the screen. But the QTE with the circle getting smaller event... no freaking key is shown.

Comment: @tombull89: Both should work...